# Is it correct/natural to say "Can you confirm receipt of the email?"

Tags: formal-language

What is the short formal wording to say "Can you confirm you have received the email?/Did you get the email?"

I thought something like "Can you confirm receipt of the email?" is it correct?

Comment: Please confirm receipt of this email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter says, "Please confirm receipt of this email.

Formal language aims to be simple, clear, and polite.  So it is natural to use an imperative to give an instruction.  But politely soften it with "please".

However your initial expression is not informal: "Can you confirm you have received the email?"  This is simple, clear and polite and is entirely formal.